# Serialize object that contains a Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

I am using Spark 2.3.1 with Java
I have an object that encapsulate a Dataset. I want to be able to serialize and deserialize this object.

My code is as follow :

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -189012460301698744L;

    public Dataset<Row> dataset;

    public MyClass(final Dataset<Row> dataset) {
        this.dataset = dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Save the current instance of MyClass into a file as a serialized object.
     */
    public void save(final String filepath, final String filename) throws Exception{
        File file = new File(filepath);
        file.mkdirs();

        file = new File(filepath+"/"+filename);
        try (final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
            oos.writeObject(this);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Create a new MyClass from a serialized MyClass object
     */
    public static MyClass load(final String filepath) throws Exception{
        final File file = new File(filepath);
        final MyClass myclass;
        try (final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
              myclass = ((MyClass) ois.readObject());
        }

        System.out.println("test 1 : "+ myclass);
        System.out.println("test 2 : "+ myclass.dataset);
        myclass.dataset.printSchema();

        return myclass;
    }      
    // Some other functions   
}
```

But the serialization does not seem to be done properly. The load() function give me the following display :

```
test 1 : MyClass@520e6089
test 2 : Invalid tree; null:
null
```

And throws a java.lang.NullPointerException on the printSchema()

What am I missing to properly serialize my object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark `Datasets` are meaningful only in the scope of the session that has been used to create these. Therefore serializing `Dataset` is utterly meaningless.

- If you want to serialize data just write `Dataset` to a persistent storage.
- If you want to "serialize" pipeline, just keep use the code (method) that takes some form of input, and returns desired `Dataset`. Don't try to serialize `Dataset` itself.